# Array guessing game

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a java noob and for a class assignment I had to create a guessing game. I have not finished the game yet but I want some advice when it comes to simplifying my array for the keyboard input. I was able to create the array for a random "5" digit number but I don't know how to simplify the array for keyboard input in the same manner for the random numbers.

Here is the part that i need advice on:

---

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random number = new Random();
    int x,y,z,a,b;
    x=number.nextInt(9); //The 9 limits the randomized number to values between between -1 & 10
    y=number.nextInt(9);
    z=number.nextInt(9);
    a=number.nextInt(9);
    b=number.nextInt(9);
    int secretNum[] = {x,y,z,a,b};
    int numOfGuess = 3;
    boolean win = false;
    
    System.out.println("Try to guess the five digit number");
    {
        while (win || numOfGuess > 0) 
        {
            int guess[]=new int[5];
            guess[0]=input.nextInt(9);
            guess[1]=input.nextInt(9);
            guess[2]=input.nextInt(9);
            guess[3]=input.nextInt(9);
            guess[4]=input.nextInt(9);
            numOfGuess--;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can simplify the number generation from your complicated method to simply:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
```

If you set max = 99999 and min = 10000, it will give you  a random 5 digit number.

For accepting user input, you're far better of using

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
guess = scan.nextLine();
```

Then use an if statement to see if the number is within the 5 digit constraints.

In terms of the loop, the comment suggested using a for loop instead of a while loop. It would be far better imo to follow his advice. i.e.

```
for (int i=0;i<maxGuesses;i++)
Listen for input
If correct, set won=1 break
else do nothing
end for loop
if won=1 Print you won
Else print You suck at guessing 5 digit numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple code is usually the best way to go:

In pseudocode:

```
secret = 10000 + number.nextInt(90000);
for (int i = 0; i < numOfGuess; i++) {
    read guess (a single int)
    if guess == secret then user wins (and exit)
}
user loses
```